# Leaflet: how to add an attribution on a GeoJSON Layer?

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I need to use a `GeoJSON` Layer on my Leaflet map. Here is a sample of my code:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
 if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent);
     }
   }

 myGeoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(data, {
             pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                   return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
             },
      onEachFeature: onEachFeature
   });
 myGeoJsonLayer.addTo(map);                         
 TOC.addOverlay(myGeoJsonLayer, "My GeoJSON Layer");
```

All is working.

Now I'd like to add an attribution on my layer but how?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with "attribution" on the layer? Give an example please.

Comment: Hi Marko! I mean this http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-attribution. The attribution is, for example, what you see, near at the lower right corner on the map here http://leafletjs.com/. If you see at the code under the map you see .... attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors' It's clear to me how to add attributions for layers based on tiles (Tilelayer), but I don't know how to do it using a GeoJson Layer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default this isn't supported, but you can tack a `getAttribution()` method on an instance like so: http://bl.ocks.org/tmcw/05c7d1164a9e62e67e6d